# Azure DevOps : How to export the Work Items from an Azure DevOps Project using REST APIs?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

My old Azure DevOps Organization has multiple projects and I'd like to export and import the Azure DevOps Project between the organizations, especially the Work Items in Boards.

[image]

I came across the Microsoft document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

Do we have any reference projects that uses `Azure DevOps REST APIs` to export and import the Azure DevOps Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there doesn't have a built-in feature to achieve your requirement.

If you use F12 to capture the network traffic you will find the related request structure like this:

[image]

CSV file was not been uploaded directly, it was firstly been parsed and then put it into the request.

It is obviously unrealistic to use such a request because it is too complicated.

A feasible solution is to use the REST API to [get the workitems information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), and then save this information to a CSV file. Then read the CSV file information and fill it into the REST API of [Create Workitems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).